# How add style for child elements with react-jss component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-jss component.
Here's my sample code:

```
<ul>
  <li className={classNames(classes.listStyleNone)}>Item 1</li>
  <li className={classNames(classes.listStyleNone)}>Item 2</li>
  <li className={classNames(classes.listStyleNone)}>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

and my code in style.js is:

```
const styles = theme => ({
    listStyleNone: {
        listStyle: 'none',
    },
})
```

Is there a way I add just a class to ul element and style it's children elements with that in react-jss component?
like this:

```
.listStyleNone > li {list-style: none;}
```

Comment: You can apply that property to the ul itself

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks all,
However for list-style it's working but for other css like padding: 10px; it's not.
So here's a better way:

```
<ul className={classNames(classes.listStyleNone)}>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

const styles = theme => ({
    listStyleNone: {
        '& li':{
            listStyle: 'none';
        }
    },
})
```

Comment: If you are using React 16.8 or greater then I will suggested to use https://styled-components.com/ (styled-components) which makes easy to use expression between css and all these things are easily doable in that.

Answer (score 8):

Please see following code snippet. I hope it will help you clearly.

```
parent: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    '& div': {
      padding: 15,
      '&:hover': {
        color: 'yellow',
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

Here is the codepen [link](https://codepen.io/it-avenger/pen/wQWamd).
If child elements of parent, will have a padding with 15px.
If you hover those div tags, text color changes.

Answer (score 2):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You can display `li`s without styles. you can make it simple like this.

```
     <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the `list-style` property on `ul` rather than `li`. You can find more info about the property here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style

Therefore, your code should look something like this:

```
<ul className={classNames(classes.listStyleNone)}>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

The error I see is here:

```
.listStyleNone > li {list-style: none;}
```

Where is should have been:

```
.listStyleNone {list-style: none;}
```